# How to "safely publish" lazily-generated effectively-immutable array

Tags: java, multithreading, final

Java's present memory model guarantees that if the only reference to an object "George" is stored into a `final` field of some other object "Joe", and neither George nor Joe have never been seen by any other thread, all operations upon George which were performed before the store will be seen by all threads as having been performed before the store.  This works out very nicely in cases where it makes sense to store into a `final` field a reference to an object which will never be mutated after that.

Is there any efficient way of achieving such semantics in cases where an object of mutable type is supposed to be lazily created (sometime after the owning object's constructor has finished execution)?  Consider the fairly simple class `ArrayThing` which encapsulates an immutable array, but it offers a method (three versions with the same nominal purpose) to return the sum of all elements prior to a specified one.  For purposes of this example, assume that many instances will be constructed without ever using that method, but on instances where that method is used, it will be used a lot; consequently, it's not worthwhile to precompute the sums when every instance of `ArrayThing` is constructed, but it is worthwhile to cache them.

```
class ArrayThing {
    final int[] mainArray;

    ArrayThing(int[] initialContents) {
        mainArray = (int[])initialContents.clone();
    }
    public int getElementAt(int index) {
        return mainArray[index];
    }

    int[] makeNewSumsArray() {
        int[] temp = new int[mainArray.length+1];
        int sum=0;
        for (int i=0; i<mainArray.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = sum;
            sum += mainArray[i];
        }
        temp[i] = sum;
        return temp;
    }

    // Unsafe version (a thread could be seen as setting sumOfPrevElements1
    // before it's seen as populating array).

    int[] sumOfPrevElements1;
    public int getSumOfElementsBefore_v1(int index) {
        int[] localElements = sumOfPrevElements1;
        if (localElements == null) {
            localElements = makeNewSumsArray();
            sumOfPrevElements1 = localElements;
        }
        return localElements[index];
    }
    static class Holder {
        public final int[] it;
        public Holder(int[] dat) { it = dat; }
    }

    // Safe version, but slower to read (adds another level of indirection
    // but no thread can possibly see a write to sumOfPreviousElements2
    // before the final field and the underlying array have been written.

    Holder sumOfPrevElements2;
    public int getSumOfElementsBefore_v2(int index) {
        Holder localElements = sumOfPrevElements2;
        if (localElements == null) {
            localElements = new Holder(makeNewSumsArray());
            sumOfPrevElements2 = localElements;
        }
        return localElements.it[index];
    }

    // Safe version, I think; but no penalty on reading speed.
    // Before storing the reference to the new array, however, it
    // creates a temporary object which is almost immediately
    // discarded; that seems rather hokey.

    int[] sumOfPrevElements3;
    public int getSumOfElementsBefore_v3(int index) {
        int[] localElements = sumOfPrevElements3;
        if (localElements == null) {
            localElements = (new Holder(makeNewSumsArray())).it;
            sumOfPrevElements3 = localElements;
        }
        return localElements[index];
    }
}
```

As with the `String#hashCode()` method, it is possible that two or more threads might see that a computation hasn't been performed, decide to perform it, and store the result.  Since all threads would end up producing identical results, that wouldn't be an issue.  With `getSumOfElementsBefore_v1()`, however, there is a different problem: Java could re-order program execution so the array reference gets written to `sumOfPrevElements1` before all the elements of the array have been written.  Another thread which called `getSumOfElementsBefore()` at that moment could see that the array wasn't null, and then proceed to read an array element which hadn't yet been written.  Oops.

From what I understand, `getSumOfElementsBefore_v2()` fixes that problem, since storing a reference to the array in final field `Holder#it` would establish a "happens-after" relationship with regard to the array element writes.  Unfortunately, that version of the code would need to create and maintain an extra heap object, and would require that every attempt to access the sum-of-elements array go through an extra level of indirection.

I think `getSumOfElementsBefore_v3()` would be cheaper but still safe. The JVM guarantees that all actions which were done to a new object before a reference is stored into a `final` field will be visible to all threads by the time any thread can see that reference.  Thus, even if other threads don't use `Holder#it` directly, the fact that they are using a reference *which was copied from that field* would establish that they can't see the reference until after everything that was done before the store has actually happened.

Even though the latter method limits the overhead (versus the unsafe method) to the times when the new array is created (rather than adding overhead to every read), it still seems rather ugly to create a new object purely for the purpose of writing and reading back a final field.  Making the array field `volatile` would achieve legitimate semantics, but would add memory-system overhead every time the field is read (a `volatile` qualifier would require that the code notice if the field has been written in another thread, but that's overkill for this application; what's necessary is merely that any thread which *does* see that the field has been written also see all writes which occurred to the array identify thereby before the reference was stored).  *Is there any way to achieve similar semantics without having to either create and abandon a superfluous temporary object, or add additional overhead every time the field is read?*?

Answer (score 1):

Your third version does *not* work. The guarantees made for a properly constructed object stored in a `final` instance field apply to reads of that `final` field only. Since the other threads don’t read that `final` variable, there is no guaranty made.

Most notably, the fact that the initialization of the array has to be completed before the array reference is stored in the `final Holder.it` variable does not say anything about when the `sumOfPrevElements3` variable will be written (as seen by other threads). In practice, a JVM might optimize away the entire `Holder` instance creation as it has no side-effects, thus the resulting code behaves like an ordinary unsafe publication of an `int[]` array.

For using the `final` field publication guaranty you have to publish the `Holder` instance containing the `final` field, there is no way around it.

---

But if that additional instance annoys you, you should really consider using a simple `volatile` variable. After all, you are making only *assumptions* about the cost of that `volatile` variable, in other words, thinking about premature optimization.

After all, detecting a change made by another thread doesn’t have to be expensive, e.g. on x86 it doesn’t even need an access to the main memory as it has cache coherence. It’s also possible that an optimizer detects that you never write to the variable again once it became non-`null`, then enabling almost all optimizations possible for ordinary fields once a non-`null` reference has been read.

---

So the conclusion is as always: measure, don’t guess. And start optimizing only once you found a real bottleneck.

Comment: If thread #1 stores a reference to a volatile field, and then a piece of code running on some arbitrary thread X copies that reference to an "ordinary" field which is then read by thread #2, would the happens-before relation not still apply?  It clearly applies if X is 2; and if X is 3, I can't see how thread 3 could copy a reference which hadn't yet been written by thread 1.  Maybe the guarantee is weaker if X happens to be 1, but it would seem strange that a guarantee which would hold when an reference is copied by an outside thread wouldn't hold if it's copied by the thread that created it.

Comment: A problem with "measure don't guess" is that it presumes that the programmer's machine is just like all of the machines on which the program will be run. The x86 memory model is rather expensive to implement in hardware, and Java is designed to allow programs to run on machines with simpler hardware. That a volatile read is cheap on today's PCs doesn't mean it won't be expensive on tomorrow's mobile platform. A quad-core platform whose sole cache-consistency mechanism is a "flush cache line" instruction could be very efficient at running code which avoided `volatile` variables, but...

Comment: ...run rather poorly with code that used such variables excessively. Using `volatile` in cases like this would make the code dependent upon a platform which makes it cheap.

Comment: That's the biggest load of utter bull poop I've ever heard in my life.  If `volatile` is expensive, then `final` will be also.  What you're saying is completely disconnected from how CPU designers actually go about adding features to their hardware.

Comment: Regarding `final`, you can find the important point in [JLS §17.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.1): “*This happens-before ordering does not transitively close with other happens-before orderings.*” so it *is* weaker than `volatile`. However, in your three thread scenario where `A` passes a reference to `B` via a `volatile` variable and `B` passes it to `C` via ordinary reference, there is no happens-before relationship between `B` and `C` and therefore no happens-before between `A` and `C`. Don’t ask about low-level, there is simply no guaranty made.

Comment: @markspace: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the guarantees for `final` only apply to objects *which have never been seen by any other thread*. Consequently, all that would be required to honor `final` semantics is to design the VM so that memory associated with an object won't get cached before a core acquires a reference, and ensure that when a constructor that wrote at least one `final` field exits, all pending writes go out to main RAM before any other writes to main RAM are performed. That could be a lot cheaper than a volatile `read`.  Otherwise...

Comment: ...I'm not sure what you mean about CPU designers. I'm not saying I expect future x86 processors to have a weaker memory model, but rather that *weak memory-consistency models are common on non-x86 processors*; the issue isn't with "adding features", but dealing with architectures that already exist.

Comment: @Holger: I interpret the comment about transitive closure as indicating that the store to a `final` field does not imply any kind of memory barrier with regard to things that could be accessed *without using the reference contained in that field*; in my code, once `Holder`'s constructor returns, from the JVM point of view, no reference to the array will exist anywhere except in a `final` field. Even if the pattern of bits in CPU register happens to match the bits in that field, and the JITter knows that, it must still treat the register as though it had been read from the field.

Comment: @Holger: Memory-chain ordering doesn't transitively close over all other happens-before relationships, but the memory-chain imposes a partial ordering (which is by definition transitive at least with regard to itself). If array elements are written before a reference is stored to a `final` field, and another thread copies that field to a non-final field, the rules given would require that the element writes would happen before any element reads by any thread using the copied reference. The only aspect I can't quite figure out is whether the thread-safety guarantees are weaker when X==1.

Comment: @supercat: Again, there is no happens-before relationship between the store to the ordinary field and the reads of that ordinary field. Therefore, the entire chain that ends with the read of the ordinary field is broken and there are no guarantees. You try to derive conclusions from what you think how the code work on low level but that is doomed to fail because, that’s not how the *specification* works. It may indeed happen in a particular environment that these three threads work but the two thread scenario fails. Not because it’s weaker but because for *both* no guarantees are made.

Comment: @Holger: Rereading the spec for the 549th time, I see that I misunderstood the sequence of events following the third bullet point under "memory chain", but I'm still bewildered as to what that sentence is trying to say.  The third bullet point for memory chain suggests that in the three-thread scenario there's a memory-chain ordering between the store of the final field, its copying by thread #3, and the read of the non-final reference by thread #2, but I'm not clear what the following sentence is trying to say about memory-chain ordering.  Can you explain it?

Comment: @Holger: I think I finally understand at least one realistic problem: the JIT has no way of knowing whether a store and reload from a `final` variable on the same thread was intended to enforce an ordering or not, and there are enough situations where a temporary object with a `final` field is never exposed that it is in general worthwhile for the JITter to eliminate such writes and any orderings they would imply. Do you know if Java has any native methods which would force the JITter to consider a reference "exposed" but which would have no other effect?

Comment: The only thing I know is http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/171 that’s contained in Oracle’s most recent Java 8 versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think your second and third examples do work (sort of, as you say the reference itself might not be noticed by another thread, which might re-assign the array.  That's a lot of extra work!).

But those examples are based on a faulty premise:  it is not true that a `volatile` field requires the reader to "notice" the change.  In fact, `volatile` and `final` fields perform exactly the same operation.  The read operation of a `volatile` or a `final` has no overhead on most CPU architectures.  I believe on a write `volatile` has a tiny amount of extra overhead.

So I would just use `volatile` here, and not worry about your supposed "optimizations".  The difference in speed, if any, is going to be extremely slight, and I'm talking like an extra 4 bytes written with a bus-lock, if that.  And your "optimized" code is pretty god-awful to read.

As a minor pendant, it is not true that final fields require you to have the sole reference to an object to make it immutable and thread safe.  The spec only requires you to prevent changes to the object.  Having the sole reference to an object is one way to prevent changes, sure.  But objects that are already immutable (like `java.lang.String` for example) can be shared without problems.

In summary: [Premature Optimization is the Root of All Evil.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).  Loose the tricky nonsense and just write a simple array update with assignment to a `volatile`.

```
volatile int[] sumOfPrevElements;
public int getSumOfElementsBefore(int index) {
    if( sumOfPrevElements != null ) return sumOfPrevElements[index];
    sumOfPrevElements = makeNewSumsArray();
    return sumOfPrevElements[index];
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should read [Java Language Specification §17.5. final Field Semantics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) first. Declaring the instance field `final` *has* an additional guaranty for the case, that the instance is not properly published, that is not made when the class simply prevents changes to the instance. The entire question is about that guaranty as the questioner wants an unsafe publication. And that won’t work in the third case. But I agree that simply declaring the variables `volatile` is much simpler and not necessarily slower.

Comment: There are some platforms such as x86 where reading a `volatile` field is just as fast as reading an ordinary one. There are other platforms where volatile reads obeying Java's semantics could be *orders of magnitude* more expensive than non-volatile reads. I would expect multi-processor ARMs of the types likely be used in mobile phones to fall somewhere in the middle, but would also expect the relative cost of `volatile` to be higher on phones with more processors.

Comment: @supercat: these multi-processor ARMs may have higher cost for `volatile` reads but these RISC CPUs are also very likely to expose that your other tricks are broken. You can’t trade off correctness for performance.

Comment: @Holger: Is the only approach which is correct and amenable to optimization to put up with the wasted allocation and extra indirection required by approach #2? Using `volatile` feels very wrong; if `getSumOfElementsBefore` is called in a loop, making the array `volatile` would force the compiler to re-fetch the array reference and do a memory synchronization on every pass through the loop, rather than fetching the reference once.  Further, it would wrongly suggest to programmers that either the contents of the array or the reference might change at any time, and code would need to see...

Comment: ...the latest value.  I wonder what kinds of memory systems the authors of the JLS were envisioning which would be able to implement the JLS efficiently but would be unable to support a means of "safe publication" with a guarantee that any thread *which never tried to dereference an object before it was published* would see the state the object held prior to publication, regardless of whether it read a reference from an "ordinary" or "final" field?

Comment: @Holger Regarding your first comment, I'm aware of the differences in the spec for volatile and final.  However I don't really follow your comment.  I think perhaps you just misworded it.  Final fields do safely publish an object.

Comment: @supercat It's been several years since I worked on ARM hardware, however I'd be surprised if an implementation of volatile worked the way you say.  Can you provide a reference to an ARM hardware document and a link that backs up your statement that volatile must be slow on ARM?  I'm interested to know.

Comment: @markspace: I've not actually worked with such things, so it's possible my understanding is outdated or faulty. On the other hand, looking at http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/ppc-supplemental/test7.pdf, I don't think all the promises made by `volatile` can be kept without doing an RMB/SYNC after each volatile read, nor do I see any reason to believe such an operation to be fast relative to the cost of a normal cache read (especially since the whole *reason* for using relaxed memory models is to simplify/accelerate the common cached-read case!).

Comment: @markspace: In practice, guarantees that are needed here would "naturally" be obtained on the "read" side (without need for a DMB there) as a consequence of address dependencies. The only thing necessary to ensure correctness on the ARM would be a DMB between the last array-element store, and the first operation that exposes the array to cross-thread access. The only danger I could see would be the JIT deciding to elide the DMB if it doesn't think it's necessary--something I can unfortunately imagine the JIT doing.

Comment: @markspace: If rather than creating a new temporary object the code stored a reference to the array into a static volatile field whose sole reason for existence was to "pretend" to make the array available to other threads, then *provided that no other array reference was visible to any other thread prior to that* I would think that any practical memory implementation would behave as required, but I really wish there were a clean way to simply say "cleanly publish this array if no other thread has seen it yet, and do whatever you like if another thread has seen it".